# Is it bad to declare an empty class?

Tags: php, oop

In my spare time, I am building a Sudoku solver to try to get the hang of OOP in PHP. A Sudoku puzzle, for those of you who don't know, is in its most common form a 9x9 matrix of numbers from 1 to 9, with 3x3 squares delineated in a tic-tac-toe like pattern. Some numbers are filled in in advance. The goal of the puzzle is to fill in the remaining numbers, so that no row, column or 3x3 square contains the same number more than once.

To do this, I made a number of classes. A `Cell` can be an element of a `Constraint`, which are the rows, columns, and 3x3 squares. A `Sudoku` is a collection of `Constraint`s and `Cell`s. I have a `SudokuSolver` class which dynamically includes source files with `SolverHelper` subclass class declarations, and instantiates one of each subclass. A helper has a `Solve()` function that takes a `Sudoku` as an argument. It examines the `Constraint`s and asks its cells to eliminate value possibilities based on what it finds. The program itself just loops over the helpers until none of them report that they were able to eliminate any possibilities anymore.

But the fact that all cells in a row or column line up, has certain corollaries that are taken advantage of in certain solution techniques. So I need to differentiate between rows/columns, and other `Constraint`s. I could have the rows and columns in different arrays, which is not a bad solution. This has the advantage of allowing a good optimization opportunity: no column ever intersects another, for instance. I could also add a boolean property `IsLinear`.

Or, and now we get to my question: I could subclass the `Constraint` class to have a `LinearConstraint`. But that class would be empty. It would not need to override anything in the `Constraint` class. It would be a pair of curly braces, and that's it; a `LinearConstraint` object is special by virtue of being an instance of its class. If I wanted or needed to have special code that pertains to linear constraints, I could always add it. My question is: is the fact that I'm considering declaring and using an empty class, a sign that I'm doing something wrong? Am I being too abstract and theoretical about this?

Comment: Would `new stdClass()` be sufficient? Or `(object) ''`?

Comment: @JaredFarrish, he asks about extending an existing class without making any changes (empty child class)

Comment: A member of the hypothetical class would have functionality that comes from its base class. What I mean is, that class wouldn't *add* anything to its base class' functionality. I am not at all considering creating an object that does nothing.

Comment: @dragoste - Ah, I see. Is it an empty class, or just one without any object type-specific methods/properties? I don't necessarily see anything wrong with that, per se.

Comment: @JaredFarrish can you explain the difference between those two?

Comment: I kind've wonder though, would `Constraint` extend `LinearConstraint`, or would/should it be the other way around? Isn't one more specific than the other in type?

Comment: An empty class would be one with nothing but a type, ie, not extended. A class extending another class is by suggestion not empty if the superclass has methods/properties, it's just not any more specified.

Comment: Maybe php // oop are not the right tools to enforce constraints. In SQL one domain + four constraints define the rules for sudoku. BTW most procedural sudoku solvers use bitmask to test / enforce the constraints, or find the solutions.

Comment: @wildplasser (cool nick btw) well, the goal of the exercise is to practice OOP so I don't much mind having to do the work myself. Also, I don't think it makes sense to use an RDBMS for solving a puzzle. First of all, those are for storing data and not for programming, and second, how would the solving go? Simply brute-force it until you've filled the sudoku up without getting constraint violation errors? That doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: I agree with you on the point that RDMSses are not intended for solving puzzels. But the constraint mechanism is intended to avoid invalid data to be present in the DB. Actually solving the puzzel involves some iteration, and that is not where DBMSses are good at. Picking the "low hanging fruit" repeatedly is all that can be done. so problems that require back-tracking are insolvable. (which is exactly the state of bitmask-solvers, which need brute-fore once the low hanging fruit has been consumed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An empty class is not at all bad. People use that in various other scenarios; especially in Exception specialisation.

I do not believe that it will be any worse than adding a flag into the `Constraint` class, to differentiate the two types. I would much rather prefer the extended class, for at least the sake of code readability.

Comment: I have the same point of view. An empty class can be useful, just to make the code more readable.

Answer (score 5):

I may be misunderstanding the question, so bear with me if I am!  From my understanding you wish to have different types of `Constriant` classes so that the `Solve()` function will act differently depending on the type of grid?  (For optimization reasons, presumably).

Extending the `Constraint` class in this way would certainly be one way of distinguishing the types, and I don't think is particularly bad practice.

You may however wish to in future have even more different types of `Constraint` (I dunno, say you went nuts and decided to do 3D sudoku or something).  In this case it may be better to turn the original `Constraint` class into an [abstract class](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php) and extend that.  You could set up how ever many subconstraints you wished, and they would all have the same functionality (plus any added functions unique to that constraint).

This way you could set up your empty `LinearConstraint` subclass and not have to worry about shuffling everything around again when you decide to have even more `Constraint` subclasses.

Comment: I think you got the gist of what I wanted to ask very well. What I'm intending to do, is finish the program up and then try to implement Killer Sudoku solving. This is like a normal Sudoku, except it doesn't come with any numbers filled in. Instead, there are areas with dotted lines around them and a number, and the numbers inside those areas have to add up to that number. So, for instance, if you have a 2x1 area that adds up to 3, it has to be a 2 and a 1. That, of course, would be an excellent way of testing my OOP skills and it would certainly allow for interesting `Constraint` subclassing.